# ruby atomic operations in multithreaded environment

Tags: ruby, multithreading, arrays

Are push and pop operations for arrays atomic?
Can i safely run

```
i = array.pop
...
array.push(i)
```

in GIL-threaded env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in the c code (array.c)
if it calls any ruby method calls (rb_funcall) then it's not thread safe, I believe.  Otherwise it should be...

You could easily override #pop et al and make them have their own synchronization.